# Is the boundary of a $k$-simplex missing some $(k-1)$-faces contractible?

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology, simplex

An $k$-simplex $T$ is the convex hull of $k+1$ affinely independent vectors  in $\mathbb{R}^k$ (for example, $0$ and the $k$ standard basis). And any convex hull formed by $k$ of them, which itself is a $(k-1)$-simplex, is called a $(k-1)$-face.

Let $S$ be the complex formed by removing the interior of $T$ (so that $S$ is homeomorphic to $S^{k-1}$.) After removing one $(k-1)$-face from $S$, the resulting space is contractible.

I am wondering after removing **some** $(k-1)$-faces from $S$, is it still contractible?
If not, for the resulting space, can the minimum $j$ such that its $j$th reduced Betti number (over rational number field) be strictly smaller than that of $S^{k-1}$ (which is $k-1$)?

Comment: Have you tried a double inductive argument over the dimension and the number of simplices? It seems to pretty easily show that the homology of the complement is trivial, from which it shouldn't be difficult to show contractibility.

Comment: To add a bit to the comment by @ConnorMalin: you can view this instead as starting with the subcomplex of $T$ consisting of a single $(k-1)$-simplex (contractible) and start adding $(k-1)$-simplices, one at a time, and prove that the result remains contractible. You're combining two contractible pieces, and if you could show their intersection was contractible, you'd be done. The intersection will be the same situation but in one dimension lower. Hence the double induction on dimension and number of simplices.

Comment: When adding the first two $(k-1)$-simplices, by inclusion and exclusion, we know their intersection has $k-1$ vertices, therefore the intersection is a $(k-2)$-simplex and thus is contractible. While adding more $(k-1)$-simples, the intersection with the already added set has $k$ vertices. How do we know the intersecction is still contractible? (And finally (after adding $k+1$ simplices), it should not be contractible.)

Comment: Oh, I see. That might be the point where @ConnorMalin means for using induction. I will try.

Comment: The argument will fail when you add the final simplex to end up with all of $S$, and it will fail because the intersection will not be contractible. Adding the 2-simplices to build the boundary of a tetrahedron might be a motivating example.

Comment: Contractibility fails already if $k=2$ and you remove all the edges but leave the vertices: The result is disconnected. But maybe you are planning to remove some lower dimensional faces as well?

Comment: I assumed that the poster wants to remove some $(k-1)$ simplices and all of their faces. That is, the maximal simplices should be a subset of the set of $(k-1)$-simplices of the complex $S$.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri: This is where it get's tricky: If I were to remove a face $\Delta$ and all its sub-faces $\sigma_i$, then I will also have to remove all the faces which contain those $\sigma_i$'s, etc. Where does it end, is unclear to me.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: as I said, you define the simplicial complex by its maximal simplices, which you choose to be a subset of the $(k-1)$-simplices of a $k$-simplex.

Comment: I know how to prove the weaker statement (the reduced Betti number stuff) by considering their homological groups and using M-V sequence. While I am not sure if they are contractible? Is it true that if two spaces and their intersection are contractible, then their union is contractible?

Comment: What tools do you know about for proving that something is contractible?

Comment: I only know the intuition that if a space can shrink to a point, then it is contractible. (Actually I remember this should be called deformation retraction, which is stronger than contractible).

Comment: Whitehead's theorem says that if the homology groups are zero and the simplicial complex is simply connected, then it is contractible. You can use that.

Comment: How can we show that the resulting space has trivial homology?

Comment: @user302934: what have you tried? Many of these comments address precisely this question.